How to create Trigger for Inventory Status Message?
I have this code:
<div class="product__specification">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="product-item__stock-value stock-status-icon-is">In Stock</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div

I need to create an element visibility trigger configuration.
Which element should I select, so that my trigger can fire properly?
In Stock - (https://i.sstatic.net/G2ictgQE.png)
Element Visibility
How can I distinguish between this HTML that uses the same class?


                            <div class="pdp-right-box">
                                <div class=" product-price__container">
                                    <div class="product-view-quantity fields-row">
                                        <div class="product-view-quantity__unit product-view-quantity__unit--half">
                                            <div class="product-view-quantity__unit-label" data-role="unit-label">Quantity</div>
                                            <div class="hidden">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="oro_product_frontend_line_item[unit]" value="each" data-name="field__unit" data-unit-precisions="{&quot;each&quot;:1}" data-err-value="1" data-err-min="1" data-err-step="1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-view-quantity__value product-view-quantity__value--half">
                                            <input type="text" id="oro_product_frontend_line_item_quantity-uid-668e9077b0d80" name="oro_product_frontend_line_item[quantity]" required="required" placeholder="QTY #" data-required="data-required" data-validation="{&quot;Oro\\Bundle\\ValidationBundle\\Validator\\Constraints\\Decimal&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;This value should be decimal number.&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:null},&quot;Oro\\Bundle\\ValidationBundle\\Validator\\Constraints\\GreaterThanZero&quot;:{&quot;value&quot;:0,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;oro.product.productlineitem.quantity.greaterThanZero&quot;,&quot;propertyPath&quot;:null,&quot;payload&quot;:null},&quot;NotBlank&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;This value should not be blank.&quot;,&quot;allowNull&quot;:false,&quot;normalizer&quot;:null,&quot;payload&quot;:null}}" data-ftid="oro_product_frontend_line_item_quantity" data-name="field__quantity" data-limit-decimals="1" aria-label="Product Quantity" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode != 13);" step="any" min="0" class="input input--full input-widget" value="1" data-bound-input-widget="no-name" pattern="" data-err-value="1" data-err-min="1" data-err-step="1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fields-row-error"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product__specification">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="product-item__stock-value stock-status-icon-bo">Expected Availability 07/15/2024</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>



and


                            <div class="pdp-right-box">
                                <div class=" product-price__container">
                                    <div class="product-view-quantity fields-row">
                                        <div class="product-view-quantity__unit product-view-quantity__unit--half">
                                            <div class="product-view-quantity__unit-label" data-role="unit-label">Quantity</div>
                                            <div class="hidden">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="oro_product_frontend_line_item[unit]" value="each" data-name="field__unit" data-unit-precisions="{&quot;each&quot;:1}" data-err-value="2" data-err-min="2" data-err-step="1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-view-quantity__value product-view-quantity__value--half">
                                            <input type="text" id="oro_product_frontend_line_item_quantity-uid-668e8e70c405f" name="oro_product_frontend_line_item[quantity]" required="required" placeholder="QTY #" data-required="data-required" data-validation="{&quot;Oro\\Bundle\\ValidationBundle\\Validator\\Constraints\\Decimal&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;This value should be decimal number.&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:null},&quot;Oro\\Bundle\\ValidationBundle\\Validator\\Constraints\\GreaterThanZero&quot;:{&quot;value&quot;:0,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;oro.product.productlineitem.quantity.greaterThanZero&quot;,&quot;propertyPath&quot;:null,&quot;payload&quot;:null},&quot;NotBlank&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;This value should not be blank.&quot;,&quot;allowNull&quot;:false,&quot;normalizer&quot;:null,&quot;payload&quot;:null}}" data-ftid="oro_product_frontend_line_item_quantity" data-name="field__quantity" data-limit-decimals="1" aria-label="Product Quantity" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode != 13);" step="any" min="0" class="input input--full input-widget" value="1" data-bound-input-widget="no-name" pattern="" data-err-value="2" data-err-min="2" data-err-step="1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fields-row-error"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product__specification">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="product-item__stock-value stock-status-icon-bo">Normally Ships within Two Business Days</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>





In your CSS selector in GTM replace every space with a dot .
Try to avoid using the Element Visibility trigger. It does polling. There's no native event to listen to. Polling may be heavy on DOM, especially when you use multiple triggers like that and unoptimized selectors.
A better way to track a status message like this would be in the context of an existing pageview event on that page, in its event parameter, using a CJS variable to get the value of the div in question. That, of course, unless the in-stock message is not available on pageload. In that case, at least add blocking triggers to your event visibility trigger so that it wouldn't try to look for the element on unrelated pages. And if it's not an SPA, then maybe make it fire once per page to stop the polling after the div is found.

I added a dot in the one space ".product-item__stock-value.stock-status-icon-is" and it is still not firing.

Copy your selector form GTM, open devtools Elements tab, press ctrl+f there and paste the selector. It should highlight your availability field. Does it highlight it?

Yes, It does highlight it.

check it in GTM preview.

I checked in GTM preview and it highlighted yellow.

no no, in GTM preview you don't check the selector, you check your triggers on the left. See if you have the visibility trigger in the events column. Make a screenshot of it and add it to your question,.

I added the preview page.

In the trigger's options check the checkbox to observe DOM and test again.

I tested it again and it is firing. I added blocking triggers for unrelated pages. I am making note that this isn't particularly the best way, but for now this works. I am going to try next with an existing page view event. I just do not know how to write the custom Java script.

you just do something like function(){return /in stock/i.test(document.querySelector(".product-item__stock-value.stock-status-icon-is").innerText)} in a CJS var and then use it in an event parameter on your pageload event.

I have two inventory status messages that both use the same class. Will I not be able to use the css selector to differentiate them? 
Expected Availability 07/15/2024
; 
  Normally Ships within Two Business Days

you can distinguish between them. Edit the original question, paste more html there for both messages.

I added to the question and pasted both HTML

you made the same mistake as before. Never show just one tag. Always show the context around it when you ask for selectors.

I updated my post to not just show one tag.

that's not enough. Keep adding tags until you start seeing a difference.

Is that enough? What should I be looking for?

Always format the code before sharing.

reformatted! How should I format it?

just use pretty much any autoformatting tool for html. I'm looking for proper indentations. Hard to read it otherwise.

I used a formatting tool to reformat. I want to make note that the "Expected Availability" text changes depending on the date.

well, now I see that you've added html that is not related and they're still too similar. Anyhow, you can make a CJS that checks the content of the div and returns true or false, then use it in your visibility trigger to block the unwanted events.
